# Is this form correct?

Tags: word-choice

I want to get a tattoo. I really like this quote: ''Nothing to fear but fear itself.'' But it is too long, so I have to make it shorter. I came up with ''only fear fear itself'' . Is it grammatically correct? I'm not native English speaker and I'm not very good at grammar.

Comment: Yes.  There is a transitive verb, ‘fear’, and i noun, ‘fear’, which can be that verb’s object.

Comment: I would put it in a slightly different order: “Fear only fear itself”?

Comment: Your tweak is grammatical, but there's a reason why 'There's nothing to fear but fear itself' is preferable.

Comment: "Fear nothing but fear."

Comment: "No fear," is a popular slogan. But skip the tattoo and get the t-shirt.